# Javascript bad export module

Tags: javascript

Help me with my code.
Stuck with importation of my javascript module. It's a simple string generator.  When a call the module, it's send my the module code source instead of string result. Apologize my english.

```js
export function randomString() {
  //defining a variable consisting alphabets in capital letter
  let characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ';

  //specify the length for the new string
  let lenString = 1; //For our purpose, we define it 1 because we need only one character
  let randomchar = ''; //Empty variable to store our single character

  //loop to select a new character in each iteration
  for (var i = 0; i < lenString; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    randomchar += characters.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
  }
  return randomchar;
}
```

my index

```js
import  {randomString} from '../../api/stringGenerator.js';
```

my button

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    var randomLetter = randomString;
    console.log(randomLetter);
  }}
>
  Random character generator
</button>
```

Comment: Is this React? It's unclear what templating you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the '()', it must be `var randomLetter = randomString();`